# How do I disable dimming of my app when showing BottomSheetDIalogFragment?

Tags: android, kotlin, bottomsheetdialogfragment

I'm currently developing an Android app in Kotlin in which I use a BottomSheetDialog Fragment. Whenever the dialog pops up, the rest of the screen is dimmed. Can I somehow disable this? I don't want to click the screen behind the fragment, I just want it to show up undimmed.
Thanks in advance:

XMl of the Fragment:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:background="@color/dark_green"
    >


    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/Title"
        android:layout_width="304dp"
        android:layout_height="50dp"
        android:layout_marginStart="50dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="50dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="20dp"
        android:lineSpacingExtra="8sp"
        android:textAlignment="center"
        android:textColor="#CCDEEE"
        android:textSize="24sp"
        android:textStyle="bold"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.571"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0.0" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/Snippet"
        android:layout_width="304dp"
        android:layout_height="50dp"
        android:layout_marginStart="50dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="90dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="50dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="20dp"
        android:lineSpacingExtra="8sp"
        android:textAlignment="center"
        android:textColor="#CCDEEE"
        android:textSize="24sp"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.571"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0.0" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/Position"
        android:layout_width="304dp"
        android:layout_height="70dp"
        android:layout_marginStart="50dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="160dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="50dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="60dp"
        android:lineSpacingExtra="8sp"
        android:textAlignment="center"
        android:textColor="#CCDEEE"
        android:textSize="24sp"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.571"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0.0" />

</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

Here is a picture of the app so you can see what I mean:

https://i.stack.imgur.com/GNdwy.jpg

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I suppose you are using Android Jetpack's Navigation Component, in case you aren't, maybe you should consider using it. You can take a look at this excellent [video](https://youtu.be/OfEOYxWVRTM) by Chet Haase of the Android Developers Team where it is explained.

Now, going to the specifics of your question, if you followed the steps in the video, you can use any of the two options that I indicate below in the code:

```
package com.example.myapp

import ...

class MyBottomSheetDialog : BottomSheetDialogFragment() {

    override fun onCreateView(
        inflater: LayoutInflater,
        container: ViewGroup?,
        savedInstanceState: Bundle?
    ): View {

        //Option 1:
        dialog?.window?.setDimAmount(0F)
        
        //Option 2:
        dialog?.window?.clearFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_DIM_BEHIND)

        return inflater.inflate(R.layout.my_dialog, container, false)
    }
}
```

Comment: Option 1 worked for me. Thank you, my friend!

Comment: @KaraokeKarsten you're welcome! Please, don't forget to mark the answer as accepted using the check mark beside the answer. Thanks!

Comment: saved my day. also you can add this line if you use custom style:
<item name="android:backgroundDimAmount">0</item>

// inside onCreate
setStyle(DialogFragment.STYLE_NO_TITLE, R.style.BottomSheetDialog)